# Fatal error: Interface 'Ratchet\Wamp\WampServerInterface' not found in C:\wamp\www\myRatchetTutorial\src\MyApp\Pusher.php on line 6

Tags: php, composer-php, ratchet

I am trying to run the Ratchet application demo but I got this error (in heading).

My file structure:

```
/bin/chat-server
/bin/push-server
/src/MyApp/Chat.php
/src/MyApp/Pusher.php
/vendor/ ..
composer.json
```

This is my Pusher class, where I got the error:

```
<?php
namespace MyApp;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Ratchet\Wamp\WampServerInterface;

class Pusher implements WampServerInterface {

    public function onUnSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic) {
    }
    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    }
    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    }
    public function onCall(ConnectionInterface $conn, $id, $topic, array $params) {
        // In this application if clients send data it's because the user hacked around in console
        $conn->callError($id, $topic, 'You are not allowed to make calls')->close();
    }
    public function onPublish(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic, $event, array $exclude, array $eligible) {
        // In this application if clients send data it's because the user hacked around in console
        $conn->close();
    }
    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
    }


        /**
     * A lookup of all the topics clients have subscribed to
     */
    protected $subscribedTopics = array();

    public function onSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic) {
        $this->subscribedTopics[$topic->getId()] = $topic;
    }

    /**
     * @param string JSON'ified string we'll receive from ZeroMQ
     */
    public function onBlogEntry($entry) {
        $entryData = json_decode($entry, true);

        // If the lookup topic object isn't set there is no one to publish to
        if (!array_key_exists($entryData['category'], $this->subscribedTopics)) {
            return;
        }

        $topic = $this->subscribedTopics[$entryData['category']];

        // re-send the data to all the clients subscribed to that category
        $topic->broadcast($entryData);
    }

    /* The rest of our methods were as they were, omitted from docs to save space */
}
```

My WampServerInterface is in:

```
C:\wamp\www\myRatchetTutorial\vendor\cboden\ratchet\src\Ratchet\Wamp\WampServerInterface.php
```

I tried to reorganize this file structure to:

```
C:\wamp\www\myRatchetTutorial\vendor\Ratchet\Wamp\WampServerInterface.php
```

but still same error.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Here is my composer.json:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "MyApp": "src"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "cboden/ratchet": "0.3.*",
        "react/zmq": "0.2.*|0.3.*"
    }
}
```

Push_server.php (include autoload file):

```
<?php
    require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $loop   = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
    $pusher = new MyApp\Pusher;

    // Listen for the web server to make a ZeroMQ push after an ajax request
    $context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);
    $pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
    $pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555'); // Binding to 127.0.0.1 means the only client that can connect is itself
    $pull->on('message', array($pusher, 'onBlogEntry'));

    // Set up our WebSocket server for clients wanting real-time updates
    $webSock = new React\Socket\Server($loop);
    $webSock->listen(8080, '0.0.0.0'); // Binding to 0.0.0.0 means remotes can connect
    $webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
        new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
            new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
                new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
                    $pusher
                )
            )
        ),
        $webSock
    );

    $loop->run();
```

Comment: Show how you autoload files and what is `composer.js` - do you mean `composer.json` ?

Comment: How I autoload files? I uploaded composer.json, is It enough? Or what do you want to see? And yes, I meant composer.json ..

Comment: You *did* include the `vendor/autoload.php` file somewhere, didn't you? ;)

Comment: Yeah, I uploaded my push_server.php file, where It is.

Comment: Any advice how to fix it? Is problem in file structure?

Comment: I still have the problem today... if I find something I will contribute !

Answer (score 1):

At the root of your project delete composer.lock and create this composer.json file

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyApp\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "cboden/ratchet": "^0.4.2",
        "react/zmq": "0.4.0"
    }
}
```

on your terminal cd to your root folder and write:

```
composer install
```

That will get you the right components.

Your folders should be like this: 
bin/push-server.php
src/Pusher.php

run the "php bin/push-server.php" terminal command from your project root folder.

If anybody found my advice useful please give me a rate because stackoverflow has blocked me from asking questions. I will really appreciate it.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You should check the autoload file, if you are using L**aravel** for example, take a look at the folder: *vendor/composer* there should be a file called *autoload_classmap* and find this line:

```
'Ratchet\\Wamp\\WampServerInterface' => $vendorDir . '/cboden/ratchet/src/Ratchet/Wamp/WampServerInterface.php',
```

If the file doesn't contains anything related to Ratchet, please make `composer dump-autoload` from the command line

Answer (score 0):

Debes implementar todos los metodos que tiene Ratchet\Wamp\WampServerInterface
en el archivo /src/Pusher.php

```
`<?php
    namespace MyApp;
    use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
    use Ratchet\Wamp\WampServerInterface;
   class Pusher implements WampServerInterface {
           protected $subscribedTopics = array();

           public function onSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic) {
                   $this->subscribedTopics[$topic->getId()] = $topic;
           }

           public function onUnSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic) {
           }

           public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
           }

           public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
           }

           public function onCall(ConnectionInterface $conn, $id, $topic, array $params) {
           // In this application if clients send data it's because the user hacked around in console
                   $conn->callError($id, $topic, 'You are not allowed to make calls')->close();
          }

          public function onPublish(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic, $event, array $exclude, array $eligible) {
    // In this application if clients send data it's because the user hacked around in console
                 $conn->close();
          }

          public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
          }
          /**
          * @param string JSON'ified string we'll receive from ZeroMQ
          */

         public function onBlogEntry($entry) {
               $entryData = json_decode($entry, true);

        // If the lookup topic object isn't set there is no one to publish to
           if (!array_key_exists($entryData['category'], $this->subscribedTopics)) {
        return;
          }

        $topic = $this->subscribedTopics[$entryData['category']];

        // re-send the data to all the clients subscribed to that category
        $topic->broadcast($entryData);
   }

    /* The rest of our methods were as they were, omitted from docs to save space */
    }
```

?>

Comment: Hi, we use English only. Please translate your answer